# TapGestureRecognizer not working in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm trying to add navigation between auth pages in flutter using TapGestureRecognizer on a TextSpan. Everything is set up but still the clicked text does not navigate to the preferred page.

part of the login ui where i'm using TapGestureRecognizer:

```
RichText(
                      text: TextSpan(
                          text: 'No account',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                          children: [
                        TextSpan(
                            recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                              ..onTap = () => widget.onClickedSignUp,
                            text: 'Click Here',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                color: Colors.black))
                      ]))
```

first part of the login.dart:

```
class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final VoidCallback onClickedSignUp;

  const LoginScreen({Key? key, required this.onClickedSignUp})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LoginScreen> createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    emailController.dispose();
    passwordController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

auth.dart:

```
class _AuthPageState extends State<AuthPage> {
  bool isLogin = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => isLogin
      ? LoginScreen(onClickedSignUp: toggle)
      : SignUpScreen(onClickedSignIn: toggle);
  void toggle() {
    setState(() {
      isLogin != isLogin;
    });
  }
}
```

main.dart:

```
class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: StreamBuilder<User?>(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Center(child: Text('Something went wrong'));
        } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return HomeScreen();
        } else {
          return AuthPage();
        }
      },
    ));
  }
}
```

I'd be grateful if anyone can help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to call the method use `()` inside a function,

```dart
TextSpan(
   recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
     ..onTap = () => widget.onClickedSignUp(),
```

And change to logic to `isLogin = !isLogin;`

Tested snippet

````dart
class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: AuthPage());
  }
}

class AuthPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const AuthPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<AuthPage> createState() => _AuthPageState();
}

class _AuthPageState extends State<AuthPage> {
  bool isLogin = true;
  void toggle() {
    debugPrint("yay");
    setState(() {
      isLogin = !isLogin;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Column(
        children: [
          Text("$isLogin"),
          SizedBox(
            height: 400,
            width: 400,
            child: isLogin ? LoginScreen(onClickedSignUp: toggle) : Text("F"),
          )
        ],
      );
}

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginScreen({Key? key, required this.onClickedSignUp})
      : super(key: key);

  final VoidCallback onClickedSignUp;

  @override
  State<LoginScreen> createState() => _LogInScreenState();
}

class _LogInScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
              text: 'No account',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              children: [
            TextSpan(
                recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                  ..onTap = () => widget.onClickedSignUp(),
                text: 'Click Here',
                style: TextStyle(
                    decoration: TextDecoration.underline, color: Colors.black))
          ])),
    );
  }
}
```
````

Comment: Changed the type to Function() instead of VoidCallback and added the (), now it's returning an error that says that setState was called during build.

The widget on which setState was called is AuthPage, and the widget which was currently being built when offending call is LoginScreen..

Comment: Is it possible other snippet is causing this new issue instead of `toggle`?

Comment: I have thought about it but I need it to change the status of the boolean variable! I haven't used it elsewhere though!

Comment: is there any other place calling setState ? It is not supposed to throw error based on my thought

Comment: The only setState used is the one I shared within the post!

Comment: Ok you are missing the logic ` isLogin = !isLogin;`

Comment: Same issue man! I really tried everything at this point!

Comment: Can you edit my snippet(TestedSnippet) and reproduce the issue. `Tested snippet` snippet should work fine for you ?

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you so much for all of this!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
..onTap = () => widget.onClickedSignUp.call(),
```

or this

```
..onTap = widget.onClickedSignUp,
```

Comment: None of them worked, unfortunately!

Comment: please share full code, both are working examples

Comment: Added more code!